# After getting all documents in collection can't add field to ArrayList, Android Studio, Java, Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

Hi guys I have a problem as I am getting the whole collection from Firebase Firestore and want get the field "topic name" in each document and add it into an ArrayList to then display this topics in a ListView. It is gonna be a part of Forum part of my application.

BUT!

It seems that it gets the documents, and reads their fields as I can see in the Logs

```
Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("topic_name"));
```

_

```
D/TAG: 6EvC4SqqDxR4TYelLOKM => Topic 1
KpXLBDzSkAb2u96knG8L => Topic 4
SY49j4RqcOI1v79EIVME => Topic 3
xS0Hw4Rj5KPGj1G7vy7T => Topic 2
```

it doesn't add it to the ArrayList or it is in some way gone because the device do not display the list.

At First I thought it is because the ArrayList when it is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final but that is not the case, as I added a test topics to check that assumption.  (Test Topic 123-Test to Topic 125) and it displays them normally, so that is not the case with ArrayList being final.

I tried putting the whole code responsible for ListView inside the onComplete method but it doesn't seem to work, because the Adapter becomes full of errors, I would like some help if possible or maybe an alternate idea on how to do it. If I replicated the topic I am sorry I tried looking for answer but was unable to find it.

The code is below:

```
public class Forum extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "TAG";
FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forum);


    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final ArrayList<String> forumTopics = new ArrayList<>();

    db.collection("forum_topics")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int count = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            forumTopics.add(count, document.getString("topic_name"));
                            count += 1;
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("topic_name"));
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    String test_string = "Test Topic 123";
    forumTopics.add(0,test_string);
    forumTopics.add(1,"Test Topic 124");
    forumTopics.add(2,"Test Topic 125");
    forumTopics.add(3,"Test Topic 126");

    ListAdapter forumAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, forumTopics);
    ListView forumListView =  findViewById(R.id.ForumListView);
    forumListView.setAdapter(forumAdapter);

    forumListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String topic = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(Forum.this, topic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

[This is the output on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWfXr.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to refresh the listview after the onComplete finishes on the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
db.collection("forum_topics")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int count = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            forumTopics.add(count, document.getString("topic_name"));
                            count += 1;
                             forumTopics.add(document.get("topic_name"));
                        }
                        forumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    ListAdapter forumAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, forumTopics);
    ListView forumListView =  findViewById(R.id.ForumListView);
    forumListView.setAdapter(forumAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks, notifying did the trick but your code had some errors but the idea worked. The code will be below your post.

Comment: Error is due to as bcoz I don't have full code :P 
Also, the idea is that, after adding data to your list, you have to notify the adapter that the data set has been changed and now you have to refresh.



Adapter initialization is getting called before onComplete() gets triggered, so you have to notify an adapter.

Comment: Yeah man because of your code I figured it out so I am very grateful, no worries about errors, the main idea clicked and it works really nice! As you can see below I put adapter on before onComplete(). But I still dont get one thing, even if it was below,  there still should be some elements in that ArrayList that were added from onComplete to start with but it works now and that's important. Thank You again! :D

Comment: We can't be sure when onComplete() gets triggered. As we are adding callback CompleteListener , so when data become available, it will trigger complete. So either you init adapter before or after, you have to notify for data change.  This is how callback mechanism works.

Comment: Please upvote the answer as well if your query gets resolved.

Comment: I am new here how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with your help below is the solution that worked in my case. Thank you everyone that helped me I am very grateful and may you have wonderful day.

```
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final ArrayList<String> forumTopics = new ArrayList<>();

    final ListAdapter forumAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, forumTopics);
    ListView forumListView =  findViewById(R.id.ForumListView);
    forumListView.setAdapter(forumAdapter);

    db.collection("forum_topics")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int count = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            forumTopics.add(count, document.getString("topic_name"));
                            count += 1;
                        }
                        ((ArrayAdapter) forumAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    forumListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String topic = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(Forum.this, topic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
```